# TRMM data download

Tags: imagery

I need help in downloading 7 day composite TRMM data (Geo-Tiff) [like this](http://trmm.gsfc.nasa.gov/publications_dir/regional_asia.html) for past 10 yrs of the SE ASIA region. It is way too confusing where to obtain the data, I wanted to analyze the precipitation over the yrs.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of sources to download *raw* [TRMM](http://trmm.gsfc.nasa.gov/) data.  One quite valuable site is the **[TRMM section of *GES DISC*](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/TRMM/) including its download portal [mirador](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/presentNavigation.pl?project=TRMM&tree=project)**   *(NASA / Goddard Earth Sciences Data and Information Service Center; [their usage policy is quite open](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/additional/citing-our-data))*. You find a variety of products there, such as daily or monthly data products (esp. check the Productes in the "Gridded" section.) ***The data is well sorted and all product types are briefly explained.***

Another source is the [ftp arcive](ftp://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/trmmdata/) of the [PPS website](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/) (NASA's *Precipitation Processing System*). Despite the site is less self-explanatory, they [provide nice preview images](ftp://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/trmmdata/Browse/V07/) of every single data set.

Binary grids of the TRMM products can be downloaded here:
ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/

The different products have quite enigmatic acronyms. I recommend to have a look at the [short readme at GES DISC](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/precipitation/documentation/TRMM_README), which gives a brief summary of each. A full description can be found in the [TRMM manual](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/TRMM/document/text/handbook_e.pdf#page=90), the [TRMM v7 manual](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/TRMM/documents/PR_algorithm_product_information/pr_manual/PR_Instruction_Manual_V7_L1.pdf), and the [PPS documentation sites](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/ppsdocuments.html). Combined from these sources, here is a *brief list of the most common Level 3 products*:

> [**3A25**](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/TRMM/documents/PR_algorithm_product_information/pr_manual/PR_Instruction_Manual_V7_L1.pdf?page=144)
>   Monthly Statistics of Rain Parameter *Global Map (Monthly)*
>
> [**3A26**](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/TRMM/documents/PR_algorithm_product_information/pr_manual/PR_Instruction_Manual_V7_L1.pdf?page=164)
>   Monthly Rain Rate using a Statistical Method; *Global Map (Monthly)*
>
> [**3A12**](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/Documents/README3A12.v7)
>   monthly means of surface precipitation rate, rain rate, convective surface precipitation rate and 28 vertical layers hydrometeor contents *(0.5° grids, Monthly)
>
> [**3B31**](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/Documents/3B31_V7_UsersGuide.txt)
>   Monthly Rainfall; *Global Map* *(Monthly)*
>
> [**3B42**](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/Documents/3B42_3B43_doc.pdf?page=4)
>   TRMM & IR Daily Rainfall; *Global Map (Daily)*
>
> [**3B43**](http://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/Documents/3B42_3B43_doc.pdf?page=4)
>   TRMM & Other Sources Monthly Rainfall; *Global Map (Monthly)*
>
> [**3B4xRT**](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/V7Documents/3B4XRT_README.pdf) similar *Near Real Time* products
>
> [**3G01**](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/README.3G01)  generated from the TRMM VIRS 1B01 (brightness temperature).  *(hourly .5° x .5° grid)*
>
> [**3G68**](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/README.3G68) TRMM instrument rain estimates.  *(hourly, .5° x .5°  or .25° x .25° grid)*

Often, the *3B42, 3B43* or *3G68* data is used to visualize rainfall estimates.

**Once you know the product code for the data you are looking for**, you should eventually be able to find a resource to download GeoTiff files directly.
For instance, [GeoTIFF files of *3B42*](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/gis/) data can be downloaded at the [*trmmopen ftp site*](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

However, I recommend to download original, gridded data of the dataset you want and do the conversion to a format you prefer yourself.

Comment: The Mirador is a very useful... i want to download 3B42 geotiff files only. is there any username n password for ftp., as sometimes its asking for it...

Comment: No. I encountered this as well; I think you can only download one file at once, and it is asking for login/password if you are trying multiple downloads.

Answer (score 2):

I am working for a plugin to download TRMM data in QGIS. I haven't submitted it yet, but I'm almost done. You can download the source code from GitHub at this link https://github.com/geobricks/geobricks_qgis_plugin_trmm, and save it in the QGIS plugins directory. Hope it helps!

Comment: The plugin has been released. You can download the original data, with a 3 hours frequency, but you can also aggregate it in daily layers. The data is available from January 1st 1998 to July 31st 2015. You can browse the plugin page here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geobricks_qgis_plugin_trmm/