# How to download GeoTIFF files of TRMM product 3B42 (rainfall estimates)

Tags: data, geotiff-tiff, imagery

I want to download GeoTIFF files of [TRMM product 3B42](http://trmm.gsfc.nasa.gov/3b42.html). *(This is a rainfall estimate derived from multiple sensors of the Tropical Rainfall Measuring Mission satellite.)*

The [*NASA/Goddard Precipitation Measurement Missions* website](http://pmm.nasa.gov/node/289#anonymous_ftp) directs me to the *TRMMopen ftp Server*: [**ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/trmmdata/GIS**](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/trmmdata/GIS)

However, this sporadically asks for username and password. How can I get them?
*Is there an alternative way to obtain this dataset?*

I need precipitation data for each 365 days and 12 month of 2013, so downloading each file one by one is quite tedious.

Comment: If commercial data, pay for an account. If not, what have you tried? Either way, contact the data provider, if anyone can help you it's them.

Comment: This question is about downloading data and access to a government web site. Please contact them on access.

Comment: This question probably lacks detail. But I do not see why it has been closed.  **(1)** _TRMM 3B42_ is a remote sensing data set (climate data)  **(2)** The NASA websites point to this particular ftp server for data download; the data is freely available if you cite properly. The login request occurs sporadically. **(3)** The variety of available download portals is not intuitive and probably confusing - GIS.SE uses are likely to have experience. _Of course it is a good idea to contact the data provider._ But why not ask here, if details are implemented? The pointer to Super User is confusing.

Comment: thank you lavarider 
I sent data provider an email and they told me what input the username and password but that did not work. I need precipitation data for each 365 days and 12 month of 2013 but I can download just one everytime without username and password!!!

Comment: Super User seemed an odd choice to me too, but perhaps the [**Open Data (beta) Stack Exchange**](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) would be a candidate site for migration/asking.  It seems strange that the data custodian would provide a username and password that does not work.  I would certainly follow up on that with them if I was anxious for the data.

Comment: The Open Data (beta) Stackexchange is a valuable hint. In **meta GIS.SE** there is a [discussion to which SE site  _questions about obtaining geospatial data_ belong](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-geospatial-data-on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Do not download multiple files at once / **use different ftp client**

You are downloading from [TRMMopen](ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/trmmdata/GIS) *(which is an official download source of the [NASA / Goddard PMM](http://pmm.nasa.gov/node/289#anonymous_ftp))*
via ***anonymous ftp***. You are only prompted a username/password dialogue if you have **multiple connections** to this ftp site, e.g. because you are attempting to download more then one file at once.

Instead, try to download **one file after another** (possibly with a short delay). You won't get the password prompt then.

***EDIT:*** If you used a web browser to download the data, **use a decent ftp client** instead (which keeps the connection between downloads) . I tested this with a variety of ftp clients, and I had no problems to download larger datasets!

*Note that you could contact the data provider and ask for alternatives in order to obtain larger datasets. They offer something like [a data subscription service in their FAQ](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/additional/faq/precipitation_faq.shtml#subscription):*

> "I would like to receive all new files generated for a data product, over a given time period, at a specified time interval (e.g., weekly). Can I set up a procedure by which specified data will be sent to me automatically?"
>
> *Yes, just contact help@disc.gsfc.nasa.gov (or 301-614-5224, voice; or 301-614-5268, fax) and request a "subscription." Information that would be needed from you are data product(s) desired, begin date, and end date. You will receive an email notification whenever data are ready for FTP pickup.*

Hovever there are alternative download sources which are probably more suited for downloading larger datasets:

### Alternative download sources

The data is available via **STORM** (Science Team On-Line Request Module):
[**https://storm-pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/storm/**](https://storm-pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/storm/)

I highly recommend that you have a look at it:

> *PPS Data Access* - to search for GPM and TRMM data, order custom
> subsets and set up subscriptions.
> *PPS Public Archive* - to access GPM and TRMM standard products via online ftp.

**Use it to obtain *custom, larger subsets* of TRMM data at once.**

They also provide a different link to the ftp server which also features the [3B42 data](ftp://pps.gsfc.nasa.gov/trmmdata/GIS/). *(I do not know if similar connection restrictions apply there though.)*

Of course you can also get the data via *http* from [GES DISC mirador](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/presentNavigation.pl?tree=project&project=TRMM&dataGroup=Gridded), *(but this is probably more suitable for single files)*, or use [TOVAS](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/precipitation/tovas).

### Data access policy

Of course, be sure to conform to the the **data access policy** which can be found in the
[3B42 / 3B43 documentation (p.40)](ftp://meso-a.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/trmmdocs/3B42_3B43_doc.pdf#page=40). Also, have a look at the (quite open) usage policy of the [GES DISC](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/additional/citing-our-data).

*The different types of TRMM data products have also been addressed in a [GIS.SE question about TRMM data download](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/89261/23934)*.

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance. that was very useful. may I ask you more questions that may arise later?

Comment: You can _accept_ the answer if it was helpful and fully addresses your posted issue. Of course you can ask more questions to the GIS.SE community. The guidance [_"How to frame a good question"_](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) is definitely worth a look; try to provide enough details in your future questions, about what you have done and what you are trying to achieve in order to elicit comprehensive answers.  _(For example, in this question, the rough amount of the data you need is a helpful detail.)_