# NetCDF file is rotated QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf, precipitation, rotate

I downloded IMERG precipitation data as NetCDF files but when I use QGIS to open them, the raster files are rotated.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide some data or code links?

Comment: Is it like https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377498/10229 ?