# Saving GEOS projection data into a NetCDF file

Tags: coordinate-system, netcdf, geos

I have full disc data in GEOS projection and I would like to save this data into a NetCDF4 file.

As the NetCDF file needs to have basic dimensions of lat, long and time (which can be set to 'None') while creating. Usually, for the subscened images (Mercator projection), I would set it as:

```
msg8_grp.createDimension('time', None)
msg8_grp.createDimension('lons', len(lon))
msg8_grp.createDimension('lats', len(lat))
```

Here in this case of goes projection, how do I go about it as there is no lat and long in the data.

Comment: Hi! I thought my question (creating netcdf files having geos projection) is related to this forum. If not could you highlight what changes you would prefer? My apologies this is the first time I am asking a question on stackexchange.

Comment: It definitely is! Please don't be discouraged by an overzealous unempathic mod closing your question instead of suggesting changes...

Comment: What format or structure is your data in currently? That might be a nice addition to the question so someone could reply with code that uses the same structure as base.

Comment: Thanks, @bugmenot123. The original format of the data is in HRIT format. I decompressed it and started processing it using PyTroll's satpy. Once opened it would be in a xarray data type, the coordinate system is in x,y instead of lat lon as the projected data is in "goes" projection. Now my issue is how can I represent the dimensions in netcdf while trying to create a netcdf file?

Comment: There's hints in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377498/10229    but to do that, You need to determine your what your data's projected coordinates are, like https://proj.org/operations/projections/geos.html or in WKT form as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128824/calculationg-lat-lon-from-geostationary-projection